# Getting individual Proximity to Collection Objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create a simple 'falloff' effect for when a specific objects gets closed to each of the objects found in a collection.
I was able to get the visual effect I wanted, however, I am unable to make this 'localized' to each of the objects in the collection. Instead it does it for all of them when I get close enough to any of the objects.

This is my current code:
[image]

Here is what it currently does:
[image: Video of Shared Falloff (Imgur)]

Is there any way to grab and iterate over the positions of each individual object in the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've understood from your question that you want a proximity (and falloff) based on the distance between the object and each element in the deforming collection.

Meaning this distance is constant for each deforming object.

[image]

So you can capture this distance before realizing,

then transmit it to the ray cast, so that it is now available in the grid context.

Example:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Well, yes that is what I am trying to do but, instead of getting the distance between the floor/grid and the Modifying collection I want to get the distance between the character object and the Modifying collection objects.
So I don't really understand how that would work without a condition after the Raycast that dictates is the 'object' you hit 1.) in the collection and 2.) in range of the player object.
When I implemented your approach it seemingly had the same issue as in the original video, unless I missed something: https://imgur.com/a/k5TSzwT

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your comment. Added a gif to illustrate the behavior.

Comment: Interesting, alright I misunderstood your code. But in any case this doesn't work for me, and I found out why, because I have a collection inside of a collection, is it possible to access sub-collections from within one? Any ideas? https://imgur.com/a/BHEdk1e

Comment: The subcollection is seen as one instance. I dont think this is possible to separate it having only the main collection has input. And this subcollection position should be the origin.

Comment: Interesting, that is a shame but a constraint I can work with, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Geometry proximity is useless in this case, you need just calculate a distance between your "Character" object (in my screenshot is just empty) and the position of each face. Vector Math do this task easily:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, so there isn't any way to differentiate between the objects inside a collection? In a programmatic way that lets you go over each and every one of them like a for-loop?